Has anyone tried to use ReactFlow with DnD/sortable libraries such as react-beautiful-dnd and dnd-kit?
So, I have a different use case with ReactFlow. A node represents a page, and pages have components. Let's assume we have added one page and some components. I'm trying to make them sortable for easy management. I tried using popular packages like react-beautiful-dnd and dnd-kit to do this, but neither of them worked. Some had issues when used in a ReactFlow playground.
Because of the complicated way ReactFlow handles zoom, the sorting gets messed up when zooming in or out. The smoothness is broken, and it becomes barely usable. I was wondering if someone could shed some light on this.
